# Which 3d game engine to start with

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I am going to start learning 3D game development but I don't know which gaming engine I should start with. I checked out some recruiting ads and many of them require knowledge on Unity. It seems this is very popular. Unreal Engine also has certain demand on the market, although I am not looking for an engine for a getting a job. They seem very popular in the market. Which would you recommend or is there any other engine I may start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unity3D

- Asset Store (Music, code, models, textures, etc.)
- Extensible in C# - A language with huge professional backing. (Microsoft, Xamarin)
- Tons of relative content on the internet.
- Jobs (Never seen a job listing for any other game engine.)

I can go on. Not that's it's the most performant and cheapest but it's definitely the one with the least risk and barrier of entry when it comes to knowledge and capital.

Answer (score 1):

**Unreal Engine**

Unreal Engine is much easier to learn than Unity.

- You dont need to program to make a good game [Blueprint](https://www.unrealengine.com/blog/blueprint-basics)
- The best documentation I have ever saw [Documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/)
- A helpful community with tons of content [Forum](https://forums.unrealengine.com/)
- Video tutorials made by epic for nearly everything [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/UnrealDevelopmentKit/playlists)
- Content updates nearly every week [Blog](https://www.unrealengine.com/blog)
- A amazing roadmap controlled by community [Roadmap](https://trello.com/b/gHooNW9I/ue4-roadmap)
- Build your game for PC, Console or Phone.

I could also do that all day long. I worked with both engines and UE4 is nearly in every point better than Unity. For 20$ / month you get full access to the source-codes. You can even subscribe for only one month and use the engine for ever.

Only if you really need a huge asset store, than use Unity.

Best Regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do whit your engine.
But for learning I'd take the Unity 3d engine it is very simple compared to other engines.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Unity and I am 13 years old so it is not so hard. But if you are a beginner I recommend you Game Maker because it is very simple to use and learn. Or Gimp because you do not need to program. You have to just drag things. And if you want to make a RPG game, you may use RPG Game Maker. Sorry for my bad English.